Free Standing Lean-to Patio cover stability question
I am planning on building a free standing 12'x20' lean-to patio cover over my ground level back deck. I was planning on doing six 12"x16" piers (located near Atlanta, GA) for the six 6x6 posts and attach them to the piers with Simpson adjustable base plate with J bolts set in the pier. But with more research I'm becoming concerned about the stability of the structure and having a "wobble" with the final product. Should I just put some of the posts in the piers/ground to ensure its rock solid or will knee braces do the job? The plan is for 6 6x6 posts, either 6x6 beams with T-Plates or 4x6 beams notched into 6x6 with lag bolts.

A drawing will go a long way toward helping people assess your design.

If you haven’t already, plan on knee braces.
